# "My places" is missing

Tags: google-maps

I have new Windows 7 machine with Chrome browser. I have opened Google Maps in browser and found that there is no "My places". How to create, save and share maps in this Google Maps version?

I have logged into account. I see just search box on the left, and +MyName, Apps, Notification, Share on the right.

Comment: Are you logged in to the browser? Or your google account on maps?

Comment: I have logged into account. I see just search box on the left, and +MyName,Apps,Notificatio,Share on the right.

Comment: Where are you located? If I recall "My Places" is not available everywhere.

Comment: You mean where is my PC geographycally? In Lithuania. But does it makes sense?

Comment: Are you able to see the ring ball icon on the bottom of the right side.Clicking would show the My place.If it is not shown please attach the snap.

Answer (score 1):

Click in the "Search" field. You should get a menu with a few of your recent searches, as well as an entry for "My maps". Click that and you'll get a list of your maps as well as a link to "See all your maps" which will open up the new "My Maps" tool.

Alternatively, click the "gear" icon in the lower right and choose "My Places". (That's the old "My Places" tool--which is likely to be deprecated in the near future--but you can easily get to the new "My Maps" tool from there.)